# Connected devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have several devices connected to my Network.  At the moment, 2 x Access points connected by ethernet (plugged into 2 network points), 1 x IPod and 1 x PC connected by WiFi.  When I query the router, it tells me one of the Access Points are connected by WiF.  How can this be?

Comment: How about you share the information your talking about specifically?

Comment: I have an Orange Livebox as router connected to a 6 point ethernet network via a D-Link switch.  As I said I have 2 TP-Link routers as access points plugged into 2 of the network points and 2 wireless devices,an IPOd and an IMac connected wirelessly.  Viewing the Router  @ 192.168.1.1 it showed the network with wired devices and Wifi devices.  It shows 3 devices as Wifi, the 2 actual Wifi devices PLUS one of the wired access points.  The other Access point shows up as wired, correctly

Comment: Update your question.  Include the data that states that the access point is connect by a WLAN connection instead of LAN.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjxh75se98wi9ue/Screenshot%202014-10-10%2018.42.52.png?dl=0

Comment: PLease see screenshot above

Comment: upload it to an image host not your personal dropbox account.

Comment: WiFi AP in "repeater mode" perhaps?

Comment: There is no setting on theses routers for 'Repeater Mode' and WDS is turned off

Comment: Try this linkhttps://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90354468/Net%20Share/Livebox%20Screenshot.pdf